# Spirit.X3 with lambda returning different parser types

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-x3

Here I try to convert a string literal to a number, where the base specifer is dynamic:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace ast {
    struct literal {
        enum base_specifier { bin, oct, hex };

        base_specifier  base;
        std::string     literal;
    };
}

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;


template<typename T>
auto as = [](auto p) { return x3::rule<struct _, T>{} = x3::as_parser(p); };


template <typename TargetT>
std::pair<bool, TargetT> convert(ast::literal const& node)
{
    auto const parse = [](ast::literal::base_specifier base, auto const& literal) {

        using base_specifier = ast::literal::base_specifier;

        auto const parser = [](base_specifier base) {
            switch(base) {
                case base_specifier::bin: {
                    using parser_type = x3::uint_parser<TargetT, 2>;
                    parser_type const p = parser_type{};
                    return as<TargetT>( p );
                }
                case base_specifier::oct: {
                    using parser_type = x3::uint_parser<TargetT, 8>;
                    parser_type const p = parser_type{};
                    return as<TargetT>( p );
                }
                case base_specifier::hex: {
                    using parser_type = x3::uint_parser<TargetT, 16>;
                    parser_type const p = parser_type{};
                    return as<TargetT>( p );
                }
                default:
                    abort();
            }
        };

        auto iter      = std::begin(literal);
        auto const end = std::cend(literal);
        TargetT attribute;

        bool parse_ok  = x3::parse(iter, end, parser(base), attribute);

        return std::make_tuple(parse_ok && (iter == end), attribute);
    };

    // other complex stuff here

    return parse(node.base, node.literal);
}


int main()
{
    ast::literal literal{ ast::literal::hex, "AFFE" };
    auto const [parse_ok, result] = convert<int32_t>(literal);
}
```

but it fails with:

```
error: return type 'rule_definition<_, uint_parser<[...], 8, [2 * ...]>, [2 * ...]>' must match previous return type
  'rule_definition<_, uint_parser<[...], 2, [2 * ...]>, [2 * ...]>' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit return type
```

The error message is clear but I don't have a solution to get the desired behaviour. On the dynamic parser selection type dispatch based on the base specifier depend other operations, hence these approach is for my use case useful. It would be especially useful, if the solution also works with real/double types and theire policies. I assume, it's more a C++ problem as of spirit.

BTW, is it save to return the specific parser in that way? It takes a copy of the instance, which may be ineffective, isn't? Are there other/better ways to handle TargetT's range/overflow detection by simple parse failure?

For convenience the code can also be found at [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fTJGniYgfkOUoqsO#wandbox-resultwindow-code-body-1).

Comment: After time I came to the conclusion that there is no simple way. One could be to use variants, or even not returning a parser. Simply call x3::parse and return the results (with/without variant to visit). Even the embedded syntax `parser(base)`would be cool for the caller parser rule...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to perform is not possible by design because:

```
returning different parser types
```

^ This is not allowed by C++ language.

---

The `rule` is intended to be a simple wrapper over your grammar with additional info (attribute type and force attribute type flag). By calling an assign operator of the `rule` it will return `rule_definition` which contains signature of an actual grammar (that's why there is `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE`).

If you came to X3 from Qi I understand your confusion. In Qi `rule` makes an actual parser and stores it into a `boost::function` (while loosing any static info and implying cost of virtual function call), but X3 `rule` is closer to Qi's [`subrule`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/nonterminal/subrule.html).

Comment: Maybe you could mention `x3::any_parser` in your answer, that [seems to be](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Pw1suRuYhgPX3iq8) what the asker needs.

Comment: @llonesmiz It is a nice "hack"! Please, post it as an answer to the question.